Blender is ignoring keyframes
I can add keyframes to the animation but as soon as I hit "play" or change the frame I am working on, everything reset to the way the animation was before.
https://youtu.be/kDc6X6R5ZAY

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Hello, press Shift K and choose Location Rotation Scale to make sure that the keyframes record locations, if it still doesn't work, please share your file

Hi, I managed to find the issue. By following a tutorial I activated Non Linear Animation (NLA) which was overwriting any changes I did. By pressing the little star and taking off the NLA everything went back to normal. The keyframes were being inserted but Blender was using the higher priority animation or something? I don't know, now going to study about NLA to understand it better and know what actually happened.

So maybe write this as an answer, it could help someone else   ;)

I managed to find the issue. By following a tutorial I activated Non Linear Animation (NLA) which was overwriting any changes I did. By pressing the little star and taking off the NLA everything went back to normal. The keyframes were being inserted but Blender was using the higher priority animation or something? I don't know, now going to study about NLA to understand it better and know what actually happened.
